# Combine Three Count Queries to One Result

Tags: sql, count

I am learning as I go, but I have reached the limit to my self growth. I am looking to have the three queries below, display in one query. But I am lost in the terminology of joins and unions.

```
SELECT    DID.display as "DisplayID",
          COUNT(AltID.REFID) as "C_AltIDs"
FROM      DID,
          AltID
WHERE     DID.REFID = AltID.REFID
GROUP BY  AltID.REFID, DID.display 
ORDER BY  COUNT(AltID.REFID) desc;


SELECT    DID.display as "DisplayID",
          COUNT(address.REFID) as "C_AltAddresses"
FROM      DID,
          address
WHERE     DID.REFID = address.REFID
GROUP BY  address.REFID, DID.display 
ORDER BY  COUNT(address.REFID) desc;


SELECT    DID.display as "DisplayID",
          COUNT(name.REFID) as "C_AltNames"
FROM      DID,
          name
WHERE     DID.REFID = name.REFID
GROUP BY  name.REFID, DID.display 
ORDER BY  COUNT(name.REFID) desc;



**Desired end result**
|DisplayID|AltIDs|AltAddresses|AltNames|
    01       32        32         2
    02        2        12         4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using correlated subqueries could work for you?

```
SELECT    
  DID.display as "DisplayID",
  (SELECT COUNT(AltID.REFID) FROM AltID WHERE REFID = DID.REFID) as "C_AltIDs",
  (SELECT COUNT(address.REFID) FROM address WHERE REFID = DID.REFID) as "C_AltAddresses",
  (SELECT COUNT(name.REFID) FROM name WHERE REFID = DID.REFID) as "C_AltNames" 
FROM DID
ORDER BY display
```

Edit: an additional solution asked for in a comment:

```
;WITH x AS (
  SELECT    
    DID.display as "DisplayID",
    (SELECT COUNT(AltID.REFID) FROM AltID WHERE REFID = DID.REFID) as "C_AltIDs",
    (SELECT COUNT(address.REFID) FROM address WHERE REFID = DID.REFID) as "C_AltAddresses",
    (SELECT COUNT(name.REFID) FROM name WHERE REFID = DID.REFID) as "C_AltNames" 
  FROM DID
) 

SELECT *, C_AltIDs+C_AltAddresses+C_AltNames AS SumOfCounts 
FROM x
```

Comment: Thanks jpw I gave your solution a shot, worked great.. JNevill haven't tried yours but thanks for the info.

Comment: Hi jpw, is it possible to put a sum total column that adds up, C_AltIDs, C_AltAddresses and C_Altnames for each displayID?

Comment: THANKS jpw... that was frustrating, I was sooo close.

Answer (score 0):

It can get confusing, for sure. When you want to join results (or tables) together, think of it this way:

1. If you want the results to be in the same row, then you'll need to a JOIN
2. If you want the results stacked on top of each other, then you'll need a UNION

In your case you want them side by side, so you'll have to join all of this together.

```
SELECT
    t1.display,
    t1.C_AltIDs,
    t2.C_AltAddresses,
    t3.C_AltNames
FROM
    (
        SELECT    DID.display as "DisplayID",
              COUNT(AltID.REFID) as "C_AltIDs"
        FROM      DID,
              AltID
        WHERE     DID.REFID = AltID.REFID
        GROUP BY  DID.display 
    ) t1

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (

        SELECT    DID.display as "DisplayID",
              COUNT(address.REFID) as "C_AltAddresses"
        FROM      DID,
              address
        WHERE     DID.REFID = address.REFID
        GROUP BY  DID.display 
    ) t2 ON
        t1.Display = t2.Display

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT    DID.display as "DisplayID",
              COUNT(name.REFID) as "C_AltNames"
        FROM      DID,
              name
        WHERE     DID.REFID = name.REFID
        GROUP BY  DID.display 
    ) t3 ON
        t1.Display = t3.Display
```

I've removed the `ORDER BY` clauses from each of our subqueries since you can't do an `ORDER BY` in a subquery. I also removed the field that was being aggregated with `COUNT()` from the `GROUP BY` clauses since it doesn't make much sense to have them in there if you are wanting to count them. For some reason MySQL allows you to funky things like that even though it's nonsensical, most RDBMSs would throw an error if you tried to `GROUP BY` on a field that you are already aggregating in the `SELECT` clause.